# Deploying a container on AWS Fargate (takes more than usual time to start when there is already a container running)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

My question is when a container is running on AWS Fargate and when I am trying to redeploy the container it takes some amount of time for the new container to spin up and the old container to vanish.

Answer (score 0):

When a fargate task is launched a new right-sized instance/microVM is made available to support the launch of the containers in the task (a task can have 1+ containers). At that time the image(s) is(are) pulled and the container(s) is(are) launched. When you stop the task the entire stack is tore down. When you re-launch the same task the whole process takes place again. This means there is no caching of the image(s). There is [an ask](https://github.com/aws/containers-roadmap/issues/696) on the public container roadmap to introduce a caching mechanism for Fargate. It's a long thread, you could read [this update](https://github.com/aws/containers-roadmap/issues/696#issuecomment-701263818) for a summary of the challenge. It's something we (container team) are looking into to address but there isn't a specific ETA.